# mongodb differences between clients

Tags: mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I'm very confused and I can't seem to find any explanations on the web. windowStart is a ISODate in my documents.

When using the mongodb-java-driver (via the mongoTemplate in Spring) the following works fine...

```
{windowStart : {$lt : new Date()}}
```

When I use MongoDb Compass GUI and type the above in the Filter it is marked as not valid. If I change it to...

```
{windowStart : {$lt : new Date('2018-10-01')}}
```

...then it is marked as valid and works

Another example...

```
{windowStart : {$gt : new Date(new Date('2018-10-01').getTime()+1000*60*60*24*64)}}
```

**Does not** work in mongodb-java-driver (via the mongoTemplate in Spring).

**Does** work in MongoDb Compass GUI

So I just can't work out what I can and cannot do. There is something I'm missing about how the client drivers work and the differences? I see lots of examples on the web for searching date ranges etc yet most don't work for me, so again I'm wondering what client they have been written for

Answer (score 0):

In the below script, you will get data between the given date
{windowStart:{$gte:ISODate('2022-12-28'),$lte:ISODate('2022-12-29')}}